# Is there a i.height parameter in appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

i tried to find any info on it, i want to use height of the row in a cycle, i know that there is i.length, but is it one for height?

example with length:

```
 for (var i = 2; i <= data.length+1; ++i)
```

i want it to look something like:

```
for (var g = 1; g<=grupa.height+1;g++)
```

this is my whole code, if you want for some reason to look at it:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ('my url');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Розклад")
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1 , sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  for (var i = 2; i <= data.length+1; ++i) 
  {
    var data1 = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,13).getValues()
    var data2 = sheet.getRange(i,8,1,13).getValues()
    var grupas = data [i-2][4]
    var cell= data [i-2][8]
    var grupa = ss.getSheetByName(grupas)
    var grupav = grupa.getRange(1,1,grupa.getLastRow(), grupa.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    for (var g = 1; g<=grupa.height+1;g++)
    {
      var grupap = grupa[0][g-1]
      Logger.log(grupap)
    }
    Logger.log(grupas)
    Logger.log(grupav)
    Logger.log(cell)
    Logger.log(data1); 
      if ( cell ==="") 
      {
          Logger.log('blank cell');
      }
      else
      {  
    Logger.log(data2)
      }  
      Logger.log(i-1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you further elaborate what do you intend to do with 'height'? Also, what are you accessing with `grupa[g-1][0]` into sheet `grupa`?

Comment: @idfurw i want to make cycle that display all cells in a column, i used for same thing .length but in for a row, i accesing each cell from collumn in a sheet with grupa [g-1][0]

Comment: @idfurw actualy i see one small proble, i change it to var grupap = grupa[0][g-1], but question is still the same

Comment: I am not sure whether I got you point correctly. Please check my answer.

Comment: @idfurw yes this what i want, but i not sure it is working, i tried to check with logger what number grupav[0].length is, and its 1, i have 3 writen cells in a column, so it should be 3, and i want undeterment number cuz it can change.

Comment: @idfurw you absolutely correct, i sorry, im kinda confused myself, way to go was: for (var j = 1; j <= grupav.length; j++)  
    {
      Logger.log(grupav [j-1][0])
    }

Comment: Sorry, it seems it has misunderstood you goal. You are correct and I have corrected my answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var grupa = ss.getSheetByName(grupas)
    var grupav = grupa.getRange(1,1,grupa.getLastRow(), grupa.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    for (var j = 0; j < grupav.length; j++) {
      /* grupav[j][0] */
    }
```

---

Row loop

```js
const col = 0;
const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (const i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  /* values[i][col] */
}
```

---

Column loop

```js
const row = 0;
const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (const j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
  /* values[row][j] */
}
```

---

Row & Column loop

```js
const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (const i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (const j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
    /* values[i][j] */
  }
}
```